Complex version of the oriented real Grassmannian?
The real Grassmannian of null lines in $\mathbb{R}^{4,2}$ can be also realized as the Shilov boundary of the complex bounded domain of complex $2\times 2$ matrices $Z$ with $Z^*Z<I.$ Is there a similar realization for oriented null lines in $\mathbb{R}^{4,2}$?
$\mathbb{R}^{4,2}$ is $\mathbb{R}^6$ with the scalar product
$$(x,y)=x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2+x_4^2-x_5^2-x_6^2.$$

What's $\mathbb{R}^{4,2}$? What do you mean by a "complex domain"?

Sorry, I have corrected my mistakes in the original post.
